# Testing React Components setState overload which takes a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a React component which uses one of the overloads for setState, but am unsure how to assert the call correctly. An example component would be:

```
class CounterComponent extends React.Component {

    updateCounter() {
        this.setState((state) => {
            return {
                counterValue: state.counterValue + 1
            };
        });
    }
}
```

The assumption here is that this method will be called asyncronously, so cannot rely on the current state, outwith the call to setState (as it may change before setState executes). Can anyone suggest how you would assert this call? The following test fails as it is simply comparing the function names.

```
it("Should call setState with the expected parameters", () => {
            const component = new CounterComponent();

            component.setState = jest.fn(() => {});
            component.state = { counterValue: 10 };

            component.updateCounter();

            const anonymous = (state) => {
                return { 
                    counterValue: state.counterValue + 1
                };
            };

            //expect(component.setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ counterValue: 11 });
            expect(component.setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith(anonymous);
        });
```

Edit: Given yohai's response below, i will add some further context as I feel i may have over simplified the problem however i do not want to re-write the entire question for clarity.

In my actual component, the state value being edited is not a simple number, it is an array of objects with the structure:

```
{ isSaving: false, hasError: false, errorMessage: ''}
```

and a few other properties. When the user clicks save, an async action is fired for each item in the array, and then the corresponding entry is updated when that action returns or is rejected. As an example, the save method would look like this:

```
onSave() {
    const { myItems } = this.state;

    myItems.forEach(item => {
        api.DoStuff(item)
            .then(response => this.handleSuccess(response, item))
            .catch(error => this.handleError(error, item));
    });
}
```

The handle success and error methods just update the object and call replaceItem:

```
handleSuccess(response, item) {
    const updated = Object.assign({}, item, { hasSaved: true });
    this.replaceItem(updated);
}

handleError(error, item) {
    const updated = Object.assign({}, item, { hasError: true });
    this.replaceItem(updated);
}
```

And replaceItem then replaces the item in the array:

```
   replaceItem(updatedItem) {
        this.setState((state) => {
            const { myItems } = state;
            const working = [...myItems];

            const itemToReplace = working.find(x => x.id == updatedItem.id);

            if (itemToReplace) {
                working.splice(working.indexOf(itemToReplace), 1, updatedItem);
            };

            return {
                myItems: working
            };
        });
    }
```

replaceItem is the method I am trying to test, and am trying to validate that it calls setState with the correct overload and a function which correctly updated the state.

My answer below details how I have solved this for myself,but comments and answers are welcome =)

@Vallerii: Testing the resulting state does seem a simpler way, however if i do, there is no way for the test to know that the method is not doing this:

```
replaceItem(updatedItem) {
    const { myItems } = state;
    const working = [...myItems];

    const itemToReplace = working.find(x => x.id == updatedItem.id);

    if (itemToReplace) {
        working.splice(working.indexOf(itemToReplace), 1, updatedItem);
    };

    this.setState({ myItems: working });
}
```

When replaceItem does not use the correct overload for setState, this code fails when called repeatedly as (I assume) react is batching updates and the state this version uses is stale.

Comment: I don't understand why you are testing `setState` in the first place. Third party libraries should test their code themselves, especially React. So basically you can assume that it works as expected unless an upstream bug is causing trouble which won't be your fault.

Comment: I am not testing setState, i am trying to test updateCounter calls setState with the correct parameters.

Comment: @DavidMcNee, you don't need to check tat setState was called. You need to check that state was set.

Comment: @DavidMcNee you test your component in a weird way. Read about enzyme. For what reason you need counter value? Lets say you show this value inside the div (<did id="counter">{this.state.counter}</div>) then you need to check that text of this div equal to value you are expecting.

Comment: like @Valerii said, you should test the result, not the internal implement. if in ther future you will change the code implementation, the test still should be pass

Comment: @yohaiz / Valerii: It would be really helpful if you could provide an example of how to test the result while accounting for react's batching of state updates, rather than just ignoring that entire section of the question and stating 'you should do this...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution to this after some further thought. I am not sure it is the best solution, but given that the `updateCounter` method in the example above passes a function into the `setState` call, I can simply get a reference to that function, execute it with a known state and check the return value is correct.

The resulting test looks like this:

```
it("Should call setState with the expected parameters", () => {

    let updateStateFunction = null;
    const component = new CounterComponent();
    component.setState = jest.fn((func) => { updateStateFunction = func;});

    component.updateCounter();

    const originalState = { counterValue: 10 };
    const expectedState =  { counterValue: 11};

    expect(component.setState).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(updateStateFunction(originalState)).toEqual(expectedState);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should test something a little bit different and it will look somthing like this (I'm using enzyme):

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import CounterComponent from './CounterComponent'

it("Should increase state by one", () => {
  const component = mount(<CounterComponent />)
  const counter = 10;
  component.setState({ counter });
  component.instance().updateCounter();
  expect(component.state().counter).toEqual(counter + 1);
});
```

Comment: As per my update, this solution does not validate that the correct overload of setState is being called. The test will pass, but once you introduce react's batching of setState, this no longer works.